# C++ Executing A coded test UI using a button. WINAPI (no MFC)

Tags: c++, winapi, coded-ui-tests

I was wondering if it is possible to execute a coded UI test which I have coded from a button click In a separate GUI application. The test project has not generated an exe that I can see.

Basically I have a c++ GUI app and when I press an OK button I would like the coded UI test to run, open a webpage and search for a certain phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodedUI test projects don't generate an exe file because they aren't intended to be run independently. You can however run CodedUI code from a C#/VB application assuming you add the proper references and initialize the playback engine.

An FYI but if you intend to distribute such an application there are dependency and license issues involved.

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer. I will have to take a different approach to solve this issue.